# doctrine mongodb. can not set array value to a field

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

we want to update many documents and set an array value [1, 2, 3] for a field.

finally we've come up with this solution:

```
$qb->updateMany()->field('targetGeo')->addToSet($qb->expr()->each([1,2,3]));
```

however, the generated query makes mongo fail:

`[MongoWriteConcernException] localhost:27017: The argument to $each in $addToSet must be an array but it was of type NumberLong64`

debugging query gives us:

```
Array (
    [type] => 5
    [multiple] => 1
    [query] => Array
        (
        )

    [newObj] => Array
        (
            [$addToSet] => Array
                (
                    [targetGeo] => Array
                        (
                            [$each] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

apparently, it's this **[$each] => 1** which makes it fail.

We can't figure out what is going wrong here. Is it a bug in query builder or we are not using it the right way?

we are using doctrine-mongodb 1.4 and doctrine-odm 1.1.3

update: we've managed to get it working with the following change in DocumentPersister.php (see added '$each' for in_array test):
[image]

Comment: What is your php version ? Can you try `array(1,2,3)` ?

Comment: PHP 5.6.30, switching to array(1,2,3) made no difference

Comment: pls see my update. We found a patch which sort of makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a bug in doctrine: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1575